# Google Map MS SQL Matching Grouped Records To Number

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, row-number, dense-rank

There are 100 Suppliers with between 500 and 1000 Items each. I want to show these on a Google map in a data layer to see an overall spread of Items, and the spread of each Supplier.

To see the spread of each Supplier, I have created 50 different shaped and coloured PNG icons that are numbered 1 to 50. I currently have this working but using complex SQL using temporary tables and joins and, because it's based on randomisation to assign the numbers, it doesn't always select every number between 1 and 50.

I wonder if there is a better way?

In summary, each of the 100 Suppliers needs a number between 1 and 50. I need to output all Items with the corresponding 'icon number'.

For example:

```
ItemID      SupplierID     Icon_Num
ABC         Supplier1      1
DEF         Supplier2      2
LMN         Supplier2      2
...
RST         Supplier50     50
XYZ         Supplier51     1
EFG         Supplier52     2
```

I know about DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER but they (I believe) cannot return to 1 after reaching 50.

Comment: .. `1+(dense_rank() over(order by SupplierID)-1)%50 as icon_num, ..`

Comment: Thanks - that's done it!

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by @lptr in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409192/google-map-ms-sql-matching-grouped-records-to-number#comment122680937_69409192)

You can use `DENSE_RANK` with a little arithmetic

```
(dense_rank() over (order by SupplierID) - 1) % 50 + 1 as icon_num
```